# Negative Value for Pool NonPaged Allocs

Tags: windows, memory

When "Pool NonPaged Allocs" got negative value.Any one has any idea about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The counters are 32-bit, so they've probably wrapped around and the software you're using is displaying the value as a signed integer. This probably indicates your system has been up for a very long time, or that you have some driver which is doing a *lot* of allocations.